# Memory error when using keras-rl for reinforcement learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, keras-rl

I use the keras-rl and run the eample of keras-rl, namely, dqn_cartpole.py successfully.
Then I change the env_name to play the Pong game, i.e., env_name = "PongNoFrameskip-v4".
All thing looks good, however, the program break suddenly with Memory Error, as shown in the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/github_repos/keras-rl-master/examples/dqn_cartpole.py", line 47, in <module>
    dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=500000, visualize=True, verbose=2)
  File "D:\github_repos\keras-rl-master\rl\core.py", line 224, in fit
    callbacks.on_episode_end(episode, episode_logs)
  File "D:\github_repos\keras-rl-master\rl\callbacks.py", line 67, in on_episode_end
    callback.on_episode_end(episode, logs=logs)
  File "D:\github_repos\keras-rl-master\rl\callbacks.py", line 191, in on_episode_end
    'obs_mean': np.mean(self.observations[episode]),
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2920, in mean
    out=out, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 59, in _mean
    arr = asanyarray(a)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 553, in asanyarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
MemoryError
```

I also rewrite the code by myself (do not use the api of keras-rl), however, similar error is occurred.
As I use the 1080Ti and 48G RAM， I'm really puzzled about the result.
What cause the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be good if you can tell, by providing the link maybe,  from where you have got the dqn_cartpole.py script. 

Also, can you use mini-batches?

Comment: https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl/blob/master/examples/dqn_cartpole.py

Comment: I know it is difficult to find the solution via the codes, I just wonder if anyone has the similar problem